# How to replace tuples of indexes in a pandas df based on data from another df containing these tuples as index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have two pandas dataframes. The first df_filtered_indexes contains tuples of indexes including (interval_label, timepoint) and looks like this:

```
data = {
    'interval_label': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'CO_Room_10': [(0, 0), (1, 80), (2, 20), (3, 10), (4, 70)],
    'CO_Room_11': [(0, 10), (1, 80), (2, 70), (3, 80), (4, 0)],
    'CO_Room_12': [(0, 40), (1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 30), (4, 10)],
    'CO_Room_13': [(0, 70), (1, 60), (2, 30), (3, 10), (4, 10)],
    'CO_Room_14': [(0, 40), (1, 70), (2, 80), (3, 0), (4, 70)],
}


df_filtered_indexes = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_filtered_indexes = df_filtered_indexes.set_index('interval_label')
```

The second dataframe is df_test_export. It contains a multi-index with two elements: interval_label and timepoints and the same (feature) columns as df_filtered_indexes including real values. The dataframe df_test_export looks like this:

```
data = {
'CO_Room_10': [0.062164, -0.013292, 0.0, 0.021749, -0.005081],
'CO_Room_11': [-0.011132, 0.052142, 0.014039, -0.009870, -0.014901],
'CO_Room_12': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.020817],
'CO_Room_13': [0.0, 0.021529, 0.0, -0.008771, 0.0],
'CO_Room_14': [0.012578, -0.011470, 0.023947, 0.028112, 0.031488]
}

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0), (0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 30), (0, 40)], names=['interval_label', 'timepoints'])

df_test_export = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
```

What I want to do is to create a new df which structured as df_filtered_indexes but instead of containing the tuples of (interval_label, timepoint), these tuples should be replaced by values from df_test_export regarding to the given interval_label, timepoint and the (feature) column.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity? Make sure your example is meaningful (for instance what should `(1, 80)` match?)